# Data Is not being added to the database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I finally got another issue I was having worked out. Now I am having an issue updating a database with my code.

The data gets put in just fine, and If I loop through the data, it shows that it is there. But when I open the DataSet Designer and "Preview Data" it doesn't show the new data. All this runs smoothly and I get no Errors or exceptions.

```vb
CUsersTableAdapter.Fill(MasterDataSet.CUsers)

Dim AddRow As MasterDataSet.CUsersRow
AddRow = MasterDataSet.CUsers.NewCUsersRow

AddRow.UserFirst = "New"
AddRow.UserLast = "User"
AddRow.UserEmail = "Test@Email.com"
AddRow.UserPhone = "555-555-5555"
AddRow.UserWorkCenter = 482126468
AddRow.UserRole = 908977894
AddRow.MergeID = 739809237

MasterDataSet.CUsers.Rows.Add(AddRow)
```

If I loop through Data Here, it shows the new row

```vb
For Each NewRow As DataRow In CUsersTableAdapter.GetData()
    Logger.WriteLog(NewRow.Item("UserFirst"))
Next

Try
    Validate()
    CUsersTableAdapter.Update(MasterDataSet.CUsers)
Catch ex As Exception
    Logger.WriteLog("Failed : " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: For your DataBase, do you have it set to compile always?

Comment: Do you have BeginTransaction? maybe you forgot commit?

Comment: I bet you are looking at the wrong database.  What's the connection string?

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Master.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Comment: When you select it in the view in Visual Studio, what is the compile option?

Comment: The mdf file is set to Content.  The DataSet is set to NONE.

Comment: Set it to: `Copy if Newer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue the whole time is the connection string was pointed to the mdf file inside the program. So nothing gets saved when running the debugger. I copied the mdf file to the desktop and changed the connection string. Everything works now so I must remember to copy the mdf to users AppData folder when installing.